# How to include the fields of a Java enum in the resulting JSON representation with JSON-B?

Tags: java, json, jsonb-api

Let's say I have the following Java enum:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum Code {
    Code1("Short text 1", "Long text 1"),
    Code2("Short text 2", "Long text 2");

    private final String shorttext;
    private final String longtext;
}
```

Then `System.out.println(JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(Code.Code1))` will result in `""Code1"`. I would like to have the following result:

```
{
  "shorttext": "Short text 1",
  "longtext": "Long text 1"
}
```

Is there a comfortable way to achive this? Maybe any Annotation I can use? Or is it mandatory to implement a custom Adapter?

By the way: `org.json.JSONObject` results in the desired format by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with JSON-B, but it seems you'll need to write a serializer as described here: http://json-b.net/docs/user-guide.html#serializersdeserializers

It will probably be similar to the `Customer` example given. Something like:

```
public static class CodeSerializer implements JsonbSerializer<Code> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Code code, JsonGenerator generator, SerializationContext ctx) {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.write("shorttext", code.getShorttext());
        generator.write("longtext", code.getLongtext());
        generator.writeEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `Map`, like this:

```
Map<String, String> textMap = new HashMap<>();
textMap.put("longtext", Code.Code1.getLongtext());
textMap.put("shorttext", Code.Code1.getShorttext());
System.out.println(JsonbBuilder.create().toJson(textMap));
```

Output: `{"longtext":"Long text 1","shorttext":"Short text 1"}`

Also you will need to add `@Getter` to your `Code enum`